# Is it possible to play Prop Hunt in GMod without CS:S?

Tags: mods, counter-strike-source, garrys-mod

I've got GMod and just about every mainstream Valve game excepting CS:S. I'd like to play Prop Hunt, a GMod game mode. Is it possible to play Prop Hunt without CS:S, possibly by obtaining the files?

Comment: if an answer comes up later and works don't forget to choose it so others who view the page see it as a solution. That `viewed` counter to the right grows daily and I'm afraid that people are reading the current 'answer' and not playing Prop Hunt!

Comment: I was wondering if I should have waited for more upvotes. Marked you as the answer, thanks.

Comment: glad to help. I came across this question when I was looking for an answer myself, later when I got my G-Mod working I came back to share the good news.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, you can (even CS:S maps)!

Downloading the appropriate files from [here](http://cscheater.era.ee/) <sup>(click on 'Garry Content')</sup> as shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxuw7C3Zs-Q)  will work <sup>(He'll show you where to place the files)</sup>.

It's just textures (and maps, if you need it) for use as an addon to Garry's Mod.

This is completely legal because there is another [more complicated] method listed on the officially [affiliated site](https://web.archive.org/web/20131228235710/https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=157993776) which not only details in its FAQ why it's legal, but it uses [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) (an official tool from Valve) with the login of `anonymous` (a free account) to get the files.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If the server is running a CS:S map, you probably won't be able to join.  (I have CS:S so I can't say for sure)  If they are running a map not prefixed for CS:S (de_, cs_, etc.) then you should be fine.  However I have friends who have Gmod without CS:S, and they're reported issues.  In playing a lot of Gmod gamemodes such as TTT or PH, they will be missing textures used by mapmakers from CS:S to make the map.  This results in the map having a lot of missing texture errors and everything appearing as purple and black checkerboard on their screen.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution, have a friend Steam Family Share CS:S with you or login to his/her account on your computer, and download it. You won't be actually playing the game, but all the necessary files are in place.